If two buttons are on top of each other, how to execute OnMouseHover for the covered button with the mouse movement in C#?
I am trying to make a Sudoku game in windows forms. The functionality of the app is like having 81 buttons (minus the given tiles) and on the other tiles I want the numbers 1 to 9 to be displayed in the small buttons when hovering.
My problem is that because you are on buttons 1-9, the mouse doesn't seem to be on the "main field button", even though those buttons are created inside.
Do you have any suggestions for executing "OnMouseHover" for the underlying button?

Yes, you can do this without any problem. But perhaps use labels rather than buttons for the numbers.

@Enigmativity do labels not break the "on hover" ?

What do you mean by the "on hover"?

Oh, you want the event to cascade down to the button below. You just wire up all of the handlers for hovering to the one delegate.

Here's a basic Form that shows two overlapping buttons. When you move the mouse over the two buttons or the form the background colour changes only when the mouse is over the underlying button.
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button UnderlyingButton = new Button()
    {
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10),
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 48),
        Text = "UnderlyingButton",
    };

    private Button OverlayButton = new Button()
    {
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 36),
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 48),
        Text = "OverlayButton",
    };

    private bool MouseIsOver(Control control)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point mousePosition = control.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        this.OverlayButton.Text = $"{mousePosition.X}, {mousePosition.Y}";
        return
            (mousePosition.X >= 0 && mousePosition.X < control.Width)
            && (mousePosition.Y >= 0 && mousePosition.Y < control.Height);
    }
    
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(this.OverlayButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.UnderlyingButton);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(280, 200);

        MouseEventHandler handler = (s, e) =>
            this.BackColor =
                this.MouseIsOver(this.UnderlyingButton)
                ? System.Drawing.Color.Red
                : System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

        this.MouseMove += handler;
        this.OverlayButton.MouseMove += handler;
        this.UnderlyingButton.MouseMove += handler;
    }
}

This is a complete form that should work by just adding the code as a class and instantiating the form.

The key here is that the handler has been added to all elements participating in the mouse movements. You just need to do the same for your buttons.

According to the program (Sudoku game) and the description of the question, the buttons that are placed on top of each other are not supposed to be selected at design time, and the overlap is determined at run time, so it should work dynamically. On the other hand, MouseHover is desired by the dear questioner, not MouseMove. Also, the main issue is that in the common part of the buttons, the event handler of both buttons should work (assuming they are completely on top of each other), which I think is not the case with your code.

@BabakM. - I'm not sure you've made good points here. Let me answer them separately.

@BabakM. - My code is written dynamically - nothing in my form was built or demonstrated at design-time. I'm not selecting anything at design-time.

@BabakM. - MoveMove or MouseHover it matters not. The concept is identical. I wanted code that the OP could run and easily see then effect they wanted.

@BabakM. - My code works if the buttons are completely over each other. I don't understand why you've made that comment.

@BabakM. - At this moment in time, my friend, you have 158 rep and I have 116,341. I have a very good understanding of how this site works. We are here to create a site of quality questions and quality answers. We do that by posting them ourselves or by coaching others into improving their postings. We're not here to criticize or belittle others. Please read the code of conduct. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

The point I meant about your code is that since you assigned a same event handler to both the form and the buttons, it will create unnecessary processor overload. Suppose the programmer performs a time-consuming task in the common event handler. In fact, if we consider after executing "MouseIsOver", your code would look like this, if the mouse was on the underlying button, it would be red, and if it was anywhere else, it would be blue.

The desired logic is that if the mouse was on the underlying button, it should be red, if it was on the upper button, it would be blue, and if it was on the common space of two buttons, it would turn blue and then red, and if it was somewhere else on the form, it would not change color.
I think like this, maybe my opinion is wrong.
